# can a dimension be set to just "0", without units?

Tags: css, dimensions, units-of-measurement

Can a dimension in css be set to "0", without any units? Because in my world "0 px" is exactly as long as "0 cm", "0 em" and even "0%".

Example:

```
width:0;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can: a non-unit `0` measurement is absolutely fine:

> Lengths refer to distance measurements and are denoted by `<length>` in the property definitions. A length is a dimension. A zero length may be represented instead as the `<number>` ‘0’. (In other words, *for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional*.)

(*Emphasis* mine).

Reference:

- [Distance units the '`<length>`' type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Setting `0` without specifying any unit is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. For zero values the unit is optional.

Personally I actually prefer using `0` over `0px`, because it's clearer that it actually was a zero value that was intended, not just a `10px` that accidentally lost its `1`.